# What is better in practice, using ==/!= or is operator?

Tags: c#, .net, performance, operators

When checking a variable for being true, false, null, etc is there a performance difference in doing a check with the traditional logical operators like `==`, `!=` vs the `is` operator in C#? Outside of any *potential* optimizations are there any reasons against using `is` where `==` and `!=` will do?

The `is` operator seems to work the same in instances with boolean and null values, but I'm curious about any possible drawbacks like performance or not well documented best practices against using `is` in place of `==`, `!=` which I haven't been able to find, thus prompting the question.

For example:

```
if (myObject == false)
{
  ...
}
```

versus

```
if (myObject is false)
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: What tests/benchmarks have you done to determine `is there a performance difference in doing a check`?

Comment: The `is` operator is LESS readable because the programmer has to figure out which of the possible meanings it has in this particular expression.

Comment: What makes you think that the performance of this operation is a major bottleneck in your application that requires not using one of these operations?

Comment: Looking at the generated IL might give you an idea of the differences.

Comment: Have you checked the generated IL?  Besides that though, why would you ever consider `is` in this circumstance?  Equality operators are pretty universal, just stick with what everyone uses and expects to be used

Comment: @RufusL Why do you think that their knowledge of the performance of the IL operations is going to be greater than their knowledge of the C# operations?

Comment: @Servy hahaha, fair point. still, it is an easy way to see what operations are being performed from each call.

Comment: @RufusL Sure, and if you have an intimate understanding of IL and not nearly as good of an understanding of C#, that's a good approach and quite easy to accomplish.  But most people aren't in that position.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like these two comparisons generate the same IL in this particular example which is comparing two booleans.

```
using System;
public class C {
    public bool Foo(bool input) {
        return input == false;
    }
    
    public bool Bar(bool input) {
        return input is false;
    }
}
```

Generated IL:

```
.method public hidebysig 
    instance bool Foo (
        bool input
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 5 (0x5)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.1
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0002: ceq
    IL_0004: ret
} // end of method C::Foo

.method public hidebysig 
    instance bool Bar (
        bool input
    ) cil managed 
{
    // Method begins at RVA 0x2050
    // Code size 5 (0x5)
    .maxstack 8

    IL_0000: ldarg.1
    IL_0001: ldc.i4.0
    IL_0002: ceq
    IL_0004: ret
} // end of method C::Bar
```

So if the generated code is the same I don't think there will be any performance difference between these two operations.